# Which is better static final string or local string variable?

Tags: java, static, local, final

```
public class TestClass{
    private static final String CONST_STRING;
    static{
        CONST_STRING=getConstString();
    }
    private static String getConstString(){
        StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
        str.append("statement1");
        str.append("statement2");
        .
        .
        .
        str.append("statementN");
        return str.toString();
    }
    //Calling frequently
    public static void display(){
        System.out.print(getConstString());
        //OR
        System.out.print(CONST_STRING);

    }
}
```

Any one please help me to understand which approach is better?
1. Storing string in constant field
2. initialize String in method

Comment: Concatenation takes a non-zero amount of time (*), so it really depends on how big N is here. However, until you can demonstrate that doing it one way or another is a significant performance issue, just go with the one which is easier to read.

Comment: (*) If you can write the method as `"statement1" + "statement2"` etc, the string will be built at compile time, so it will make literally no difference.